# Flex container image slider carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox

I am trying to make an image carousel with a flex container.

I want the carousel to slide the images when certain time passes. The first iteration is okay but when the second one comes, it does nothing.

I do not want to use a third party carousel. Thanks for your answers

```
$(document).ready( function() {

var carouselWidth = $('.rm-carousel-item').width();

var carIndex = 0;
var playCarousel = setInterval(function(){ autoPlayCarousel(carIndex) }, 3000);

function autoPlayCarousel(index){
    var items = $('.racmma-carousel').children();

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
        console.log(i);
        var item = items.get(i);
        $(item).css({'transform' : 'translate(' + -carouselWidth +'px, ' + 0 + 'px)'});
    }
    carIndex += 1;
    //if ( carIndex > items.length) { carIndex = 0; }
}
});
```

This is the fiddle of what I am getting :

https://jsfiddle.net/j565rdk8/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost good, you simply need to increase the translation on each iteration as actually your are always changing the same value. You need to do something like this :

```
'transform': 'translate(' + -(index * carouselWidth) + 'px, ' + 0 + 'px)'
```

The translaion become bigger on each iteration as the index is incrementing :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var carouselWidth = $('.rm-carousel-item').width();

  var carIndex = 0;
  var playCarousel = setInterval(function() {
    autoPlayCarousel(carIndex)
  }, 1000);

  function autoPlayCarousel(index) {
    var items = $('.racmma-carousel').children();

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      var item = items.get(i);
      $(item).css({
        'transform': 'translate(' + -(index * carouselWidth) + 'px, ' + 0 + 'px)'
      });
    }
    carIndex += 1;
    if (carIndex == items.length) {
      carIndex = 0;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.racmma-carousel {
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 10000%;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.rm-carousel-item {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: 0.6s all ease-in-out;
  min-height: 200px;
}

#carousel-item-1 {
  background-image: url(/bd/media/hero.jpg);
  background-color: blue;
}

#carousel-item-2 {
  background-image: url(/bd/media/hero2.jpg);
  background-color: red;
}

#carousel-item-3 {
  background-image: url(/bd/media/hero3.jpg);
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="racmma-carousel">
  <div class="rm-carousel-item" id="carousel-item-1">

  </div>
  <div class="rm-carousel-item" id="carousel-item-2">

  </div>
  <div class="rm-carousel-item" id="carousel-item-3">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Dude thankss!! I was doing that same thing but with the "i" so it didnt work.. I didnt thought about using index instead!

Comment: This is a little off-topic but, how will be possible so that the first goes last and so on, so that "rollback" doesnt happen

Comment: @Rialcom let see how with this ;)

Comment: @Rialcom unfortunately it won't be easy with the actual code, do you want another approach ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes, any help to figure it out will be really nice! Thanks for your time!

Comment: @TemaniAfif I was thinking like hiding the div and translating it to the right of the last element, also moving its position in the array. What was your approach?

Comment: @Rialcom my approach is to translate the image and then put i back, using some z-index will make it hidden under the other so we cannot see the second translate. so almost like yours ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161088/discussion-between-rialcom-and-temani-afif).